# re installing HP Photosmart C4240 allin

Tags: software-installation

how do I install a HP Photosmart C4240 all in one printer scanner copier on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal window

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

Enter

`hp-setup`

Follow the instructions on the screen